# Can someone identify this part of the engine on a TVS Apache

Tags: engine, motorcycle

I tried looking up everywhere, and this is unique to this bike.

Can someone identify the below component.

Looks like a pipe connecting the engine with starter motor.

[image]

Close up of the engine , both sides.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need a bigger picture

Comment: We need a picture with better detail, as in detail as to *which* part is actually being asked about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Oil Line]
**EDITED**

I'm going to assume that you mixed up the arrow-head direction. The part is definitely not connected to the starter.
Though I'd earlier thought that it was for oil return from the Head , I believe it could also be some sort of reinforcement member. The bolts throw me off though, (could it be hollow to let the oil through?) You may need to look this up. 
I was able to find it on page 7 of the [service manual](http://lifeon-2-wheels.blogspot.in/2013/01/service-manual-and-part-manual-for-tvs.html) online.
[image]

[image]

Part No. - M1010260

**EDIT 2**
Your bike has overhead camshaft. This is definitely the oil line running from the pump .
The bolts, as I suspected are hollow bolts.
[image] 
[image]

PS - I had to do this to a stranger's bike cause you wouldn't do it to yours.
Only kidding.

Comment: Lol.. Yeah mixed up arrow head :-) , this thing has been bothering me since i got the bike 8 years ago lol

Comment: @Anarach check the edit. Could you confirm the above ?

Comment: Hmmm.. yeah thats the one

Comment: @Anarach check edit . Hope you have your answer

Answer (score 3):

The arrow in the low resolution picture appears to point to the frame. The third picture shows the same side of the engine and a clear view of said frame.